# Include app in ROM as system app

Tags: android, android-source

I want to build a rom from source and include my app as system app. What I've tried:

1.Copy my project into `$SOURCE_DIR/packages/apps/`

2.add Android.mk in root folder of my project:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_STATIC_JAVA_LIBRARIES := android-common
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(call all-java-files-under, src)
LOCAL_PACKAGE_NAME := packagename
LOCAL_CERTIFICATE := platform
include $(BUILD_PACKAGE)
include $(call all-makefiles-under,$(LOCAL_PATH))
```

3.Configure building for maguro and:

```
make -j1 otapackage
```

But I don't see my app in output image's `/system/app` directory.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do not see in your mk file the following line:

```
LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := optional
```

And I guess you have just forgotten to include your package into `build/target/product/core.mk` file under the section `PRODUCT_PACKAGES`

Comment: "PRODUCT_PACKAGES +=" I guess that's it. And I guess that corresponds to LOCAL_PACKAGE_NAME in my Android.mk? And why should I include LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS?

Comment: To my point of view, LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS controls what software is added to what build. To your other questions the answer is yes )

Comment: Do any of you have links to documentation on the process to do something like include your app in the system image so that your app is preinstalled?